# Group entries in a 3d array by one deep column and sum another deep column per group

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

How can I group by adult price then get the sum of adult count per group.

Sample input:

```
[
    [
        'Reservation' => ['adult_price' => 2000, 'adult_count' => 2],
    ],
    [
        'Reservation' => ['adult_price' => 2000, 'adult_count' => 1],
    ],
    [
        'Reservation' => ['adult_price' => 300, 'adult_count' => 1],
    ],
]
```

Expected Result:

```
[
    [
        'Reservation' => ['adult_price' => 2000, 'adult_count' => 3],
    ],
    [
        'Reservation' => ['adult_price' => 300, 'adult_count' => 1],
    ],
]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$grouped = [];

foreach ($array as $item) {
    $item = $item["Reservation"];
    $currentValue = isset($grouped[$item["adult_price"]]) ? $grouped[$item["adult_price"]] : 0;
    $grouped[$item["adult_price"]] = $currentValue + $item["adult_count"];
}

$buildArray = [];

foreach ($grouped as $price => $count) {
    $buildArray[] = ["Reservation" => ["adult_price" => $price, "adult_count" => $count]];
}

print_r($buildArray);
```

https://3v4l.org/iZZ4m

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
function summarize($ReservationArr){
  $summed = [];
  foreach ($ReservationArr as $one){

    $adult_price = $one["Reservation"]["adult_price"];
    $adult_count= $one["Reservation"]["adult_count"];
    if (isset( $summed[$adult_price])){
            $summed[$adult_price] += (int)$adult_count;
    } else {
          $summed[$adult_price] = (int)$adult_count;
        }
  }
    // now rebuild:
    $result = [];
    foreach ($summed as $price => $number){
        $result[] = array("Reservation" => array("adult_price" => $price, "adult_count" => $number));
    }
    return $result;
}

$test = [];
$test[] = array("Reservation" => array("adult_price" => 2000, "adult_count" => 2));
$test[] = array("Reservation" => array("adult_price" => 1000, "adult_count" => 1));
$test[] = array("Reservation" => array("adult_price" => 500, "adult_count" => 4));
$test[] = array("Reservation" => array("adult_price" => 2000, "adult_count" => 3));

$test[] = array("Reservation" => array("adult_price" => 2000, "adult_count" => 2));
$test[] = array("Reservation" => array("adult_price" => 1000, "adult_count" => 1));
$test[] = array("Reservation" => array("adult_price" => 500, "adult_count" => 4));
$test[] = array("Reservation" => array("adult_price" => 2000, "adult_count" => 3));

$res = summarize($test);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using two loops is too much unnecessary work.  Treat the output array as a continuously updated lookup array.  This will determine if you are dealing with a new adult_price or one that has been encountered before.  Use the `$row['Reservation']['adult_price']` value as new temporary first level keys -- this assists `isset()` in knowing if the whole row should be saved, or if the adult_count should be added to the stored count.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gQlV3))

```
$rows = [
    ["Reservation" => ["adult_price" => 2000, "adult_count" => 2]],
    ["Reservation" => ["adult_price" => 1000, "adult_count" => 1]],
    ["Reservation" => ["adult_price" => 500, "adult_count" => 4]],
    ["Reservation" => ["adult_price" => 2000, "adult_count" => 3]],
    ["Reservation" => ["adult_price" => 2000, "adult_count" => 2]],
    ["Reservation" => ["adult_price" => 1000, "adult_count" => 1]],
    ["Reservation" => ["adult_price" => 500, "adult_count" => 4]],
    ["Reservation" => ["adult_price" => 2000, "adult_count" => 3]],
];

$result = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['Reservation']['adult_price']])) {
        $result[$row['Reservation']['adult_price']] = $row;
    } else {
        $result[$row['Reservation']['adult_price']]['Reservation']['adult_count'] += $row['Reservation']['adult_count'];
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Alternatively, this may cause less eye-strain:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $key = $row['Reservation']['adult_price'];
    if (!isset($result[$key])) {
        $result[$key] = $row;
    } else {
        $result[$key]['Reservation']['adult_count'] += $row['Reservation']['adult_count'];
    }
}
```

Or destructure the row data into convenient variables and push unique rows into the result array as references, then only add new counts to store counts upon re-encountering a price group.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/l5lnV))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    ['Reservation' => ['adult_price' => $p, 'adult_count' => $c]] = $row;
    if (!isset($ref[$p])) {
        $ref[$p] = $row;
        $result[] =& $ref[$p];
        continue;
    }
    $ref[$p]['Reservation']['adult_count'] += $c;
}
var_export($result);
```

Output: (from either snippet)

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Reservation' => 
    array (
      'adult_price' => 2000,
      'adult_count' => 10,
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Reservation' => 
    array (
      'adult_price' => 1000,
      'adult_count' => 2,
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'Reservation' => 
    array (
      'adult_price' => 500,
      'adult_count' => 8,
    ),
  ),
)
```